# Sharepoint workflow verification

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Best regard.

I have a problem with a workflow that is stuck and I really don't know how to approach the issue to solve it. No matter how many times I click "resume this workflow" the problem persists. I understand that it has to do with an adjustment in a thread created in SP Designer 2013, but I do not have much knowledge about this environment and that is why I am looking for guidance about this structure.

I appreciate your collaboration about this.

[error]
[image]

I tried to restart the workflow, but the error persists. I also went into SP Designer 2013 and verified that the workflow was active. But I don't know how to change or manipulate the lines of code to fix the problem.